# Change focus color of Entry control in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

How can you change the focus border and cursor color in a Entry control in Xamarin forms? In the emulator it is standard red?

I added this in my Android project

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntryControl), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But can't find the property for border or cursor?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change Entry focus color in Android Project in the style.xml file. The path is: Resources/values/styles.xml

Then, look at the "colorAccent" property to set the custom color.

[image: ColorAccent in Xamarin Android Project]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  public class EntryCustomRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);

            // set the cursor color the same as the entry TextColor
            IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
            IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = 
                   JNIEnv.GetFieldID(IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
            // replace 0 with a Resource.Drawable.my_cursor 
            JNIEnv.SetField(Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you have a TextColor set for the Entry, the cursor will use that color if you keep '0' value for resource id

Comment: Aaah but i'm using Xamarin Forms, not native Android

Comment: Ok Will try this later!

Comment: Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, try this code to change iOS entry looks like native Android entry**
*Add this renderer in your ios section ; also Focus and unfocus color is changing*.

> remember this line to add above namespace
>    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    private CALayer _borderLayer;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
            return;

        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

        var element = Element as Entry;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        //DrawBorder(element.BorderColor.ToCGColor());
        DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));

        e.NewElement.Unfocused += (sender, evt) =>
        {
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156)); // unfocused, set color

        };
        e.NewElement.Focused += (sender, evt) =>
        {
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(245, 0, 47)); ; // focused, set color
        };
    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        var element = Element as Entry;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
    }
    public override CGRect Frame
    {
        get { return base.Frame; }
        set
        {
            base.Frame = value;

            var element = Element as Entry;
            if (element == null)
                return;

            // DrawBorder(element.BorderColor.ToCGColor());
            DrawBorder(UIColor.FromRGB(156, 156, 156));
        }
    }
    private void DrawBorder(UIColor borderColor)
    {
        if (Frame.Height <= 0 || Frame.Width <= 0)
            return;

        if (_borderLayer == null)
        {
            _borderLayer = new CALayer
            {
                MasksToBounds = true,
                Frame = new CGRect(0f, Frame.Height - 1, Frame.Width, 1f),
                BorderColor = borderColor.CGColor,
                BorderWidth = 1.0f
            };

            Control.Layer.AddSublayer(_borderLayer);
            Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        }
        else
        {
            _borderLayer.BorderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
            _borderLayer.Frame = new CGRect(0f, Frame.Height - 1, Frame.Width, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```