# How to change color of selected text for Entry and Editor controls in MAUI.NET

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, selectedtext, windows-themes

Like in the title.

I cleared all styles and still - when the user select text in entry or editor there is coloured background of this selected text. I want to set what colour it would be. How to do that?

Right now this is the Windows theme colour but it made the application ugly, as this colour is irrelevant to my layout. How to set this colour for my own or disable this Windows theme styling at all.

Comment: Try using [Visual states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states). However, I don't know if that works when only some of the text is selected - I've only used when an entire element (e.g. a label) is picked.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I tried but there is no property that I can use, and this is not depending on the VisualState or not. There is no property like SelectedColor or so in the API of Entry control.

Comment: I managed to remove the underscore of the focused entry (also coloured by Windows colour) by addition of         <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness> into <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources> in Platforms/Windows/App.xaml but can't sucess with this question aim <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxSelectionHighlightColor">blue</SolidColorBrush> doesn't work

Comment: I think you will have to make a [custom handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize), and change it in Windows-specific code.

Comment: Thank you for a hint. It looks like this is the way to go. I would give it a try.

Comment: You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301150/change-focus-color-of-entry-control-in-xamarin-forms).

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging after reading Jaydopartu's comment and found a possible solution. Go into App.xaml in the platform>windows directory for your maui project.

You need to add `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlSelectionHighlightColor" Color="COLORYOUWANTHERE"/>`

This worked for me on .NET 7.0 Maui and this other thread I found looks like It has a lot of properties that can be set. [Link to other thread I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70573769/23168711)